# How to remove multiple child nodes recursively without messing up the indices?

Tags: javascript, dom

JSFiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/sFe45/

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Foo</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

var target;
var anchor;

function removeTags(node){
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var childNode = node.childNodes[i];
        if (childNode.nodeType == 1) {
            node.removeChild(childNode);
            continue;
        } 
        removeTags(childNode);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    target = document.getElementById('target');
    anchor = document.getElementById('anchor');
    anchor.onclick = function() {
        removeTags(target);
    }
}

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="target">
            <p>
                <a href="#" id="anchor">Remove tags</a>
            </p>

            Text

            <p>Para 1</p>
            <p>Para 2</p>
            <p>Para 3</p>
            <p>Para 4</p>
            <p>Para 5</p>
            <p>Para 6</p>
            <p>Para 7</p>
            <p>Para 8</p>
            <p>Para 9</p>
            <p>Para 10</p>
            Text
        </div>
</html>
```

​As you will notice in the JSFiddle URL, when you click the "Remove tags" link, `removeTags()` fails to remove alternate paragraph elements. The reason is when a `removeTags` removes a child node from its parent, the remaining child nodes shift one place to left in `node.childNodes` array.

How can this be fixed in a neat way?

Comment: i edited the indents, but check out that missing `</body>`

Comment: @Joseph: He/she hasn't declared the doctype, but in HTML5, `body` is an [optional tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags), which is just a reflection of what browsers actually do. (Would *I* do that? No. But...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder good point. but it's better when you close it. avoids confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count backward:

```
for (var i = node.childNodes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFe45/1/)

Alternately, you can use [`lastChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-61AD09FB) and [`previousSibling`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-640FB3C8):

```
var prev;
for (var child = node.lastChild; child; child = prev) {
    prev = child.previousSibling;

    if (child.nodeType == 1) {
        node.removeChild(child);
        continue;
    } 

    removeTags(child);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sFe45/2/)

Separately:

> ...the remaining child nodes shift one place to left in `node.childNodes` array...

[`NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-536297177)s are **not** arrays.